# Why is floating action button disappearing after animation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, floating-action-button

I've a fragment which contains several elements, one of them is a fab, I'm trying to make a fab show/hide when I press another fab. I've created my own animation and set up the animations in OnClickListener method.

The  problem comes when the animation ends, because the fab which appeared immediately disappears, so I can't use it, and if I force the show() method on the fab, the button appears the way the method works, but I want to use my own animation, with custom scales and duration, etc.

The animation xml is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="0.8"
        android:toYScale="0.8"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="300"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    </scale>

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="300">
    </alpha>
</set>
```

In the fragment onCreateView() my code looks like this:

```
        FloatingActionButton fab1 = view.findViewById(R.id.fab1);
        FloatingActionButton fab2 = view.findViewById(R.id.fab2);
        boolean isVisible = false;
        fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!isVisible){
                    fab.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.fab_open));
                    //this is for the button to regain clickable property, disabled by default in layout
                    fab.setClickable(true); 
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Fab already shown",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

This are the fab in the layout file:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/erase_96px" />
```

I've tried this kind of solution before, but with other kind of fab, maybe this matters, in the past I used this and it worked just fine:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/myFab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="168dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/ScrollViewCambio"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="right|bottom"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/eraseFab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/eraseFab"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/eraseFab"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/custom25"
        android:tint="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one change required anim.setFillAfter(true). It will keep the final state of your animation.

Please refer to my below code.

```
    final Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.fab_open);
    fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(!isVisible){
                        fab.startAnimation(anim);
                        //this is for the button to regain clickable property, disabled by default in layout
                        anim.setFillAfter(true);    
                        fab.setClickable(true); 
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Fab already shown",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the setFillAfter(true) just after the Animation definition, becouse my app it's a little bit more complicated that the showed example, and I use the animation several times, but it worked as expected.

Comment: Great, I am very happy that the solution helped you :)